# PayPal REST Api Add Tracking for digital goods

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Regarding this source:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/#add-tracking-information-without-tracking-numbers

I want to use the REST API of PayPal for add tracking for delivered digital goods. As there is no real shipping process, due to the fact that those goods are delivered via email within seconds, I would like to put the status of those orders to "DELIVERED".
But in the documentation there is this hint regarding the delivered status:
When the tracking number was uploaded, the item had already been delivered.

As I don't have a tracking number, I really don't know how to handle this.
Does anybody have expierience with the tracking api for digital goods?

I've tried to contact PayPal but did not receive a clearifing message.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking numbers only apply to physically shipped products. For orders in which all goods are delivered digitally, the checkout should specify `NO_SHIPPING` in the create order API call. Then no shipping address will be collected, and no tracking information will be expected nor relevant.

Comment: I've already implemented:
`<ebl:NoShipping>1</ebl:NoShipping>`

The problem is, that PayPal asks us to track the delivery status of our orders to have us access our money earlier. Right now it's stuck for 21 days, before we can access it.
When we mark the orders as shipped, we get our money earlier. So thats why I would like to automate the process, even though I have already no_shipping activated